# Ruby JSON response weird escaped characters

Tags: ruby, json, rest-client

confused here. First time using RestClient over HTTParty. But when I make a request, I'm getting a

```
response = RestClient.get(url, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json, :'authorization' => token)

=> "{\"items\":[{\"tag\":\"#R0YL2RP\"},{\"tag\":\"#8U9PVV0R\"}]}"
```

So what's up with all the `\`? And how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the response printed to the console, as the result of evaluation of a REPL expression. This display is printed using `#inspect`, which, for strings, gives the representation of the string itself (so you can just plop it into the code); in this representation, backslashes and double quotes are escaped:

```
"foo" + "bar"
#  => "foobar"       - note the quotes
```

If you print the string itself, you don't get it escaped:

```
puts "foo" + "bar"
# foobar            - note: no quotes
#  => nil           - return value of `puts`
```

If your string contains quotes:

```
puts "\""
# "
#  => nil

"\""
#  => "\""
```

Your JSON is fine - just getting escaped in printing. Do `puts response` instead of just `response` and see.

Comment: That is perfect. You're brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok. You need to parse json response with `JSON.parse` method

Require json module in your code:

```
require 'json'
```

And parse your response JSON string:

```
JSON.parse(response)
```

[Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your response is in string format and it looks OK. To convert this to an actual JSON object

`require 'json'`

and

`JSON.parse(json_string)`